# After ul li's float left ,how can I make text-align center?

Tags: html, css

We always make`li` `float:left` to make a navigation bar, but after that, the text will also float left. How can I make text center? I have already used `text-align:center;`, but it isn't working, which can't make y-axis in the center. Someone said I can use `padding` to make text-align center, but every time we add an `li`, I might change the padding, Or can we use `display:inline`? Can someone gives me other efficient ways? 
Following is my css code:

```
ul{
list-style:none;
}
ul li{
float: left;
font-size: 20px;
width: 130px;
height: 50px;
border-right: 1px solid blue;
text-align:center;
}
```

the html code:

```
<body>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: Will you post your sample code or create [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: `float` and `text-align` are two independend properties. Show CSS coed what exacly you tried and than show an image how it should be in real.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aligning on the y-axis is referred to as `vertical-align`, it has nothing to do with `text-align`.

You have two options to align your items vertically:

Add `line-height` **or** add `padding`

**Option 1** - line-height

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
}
ul li{
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
```

**Option 2:** Padding

```css
ul{
list-style:none;
}
ul li{
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0;
  border-right: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<body>
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
</ul>
</body>
```

In both cases if you want to center the text as well add `text-align: center;` and add a width to the `li` element.

Comment: ,why should we add display:block?Isn't li a block tag？I have already tried,but the first method can't work.

Comment: Did you give it the width, the same as my snippet above?

Comment: Yes,I just did what you had written.You can see it in my question

Comment: Please see my updated answer - aligning on the Y-axis is different from text-center... I have explained above.

Comment: ,Thank you, I tried again,and it works.But I am confuse about the first Option.Why can we use'line-height' without make 'li' `display inline`? Isn't `li` a block tag?

Comment: By default `li` is a list-item, which is essentially a block element. You can use line-height because you have used float... this basically overrides any `display:inline;` setting. If you don't use `float` and choose only `display: inline;` then you will need to use the padding method mentioned above as the inline element will not respond to height.

Answer (score 0):

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Coffee</li>
    <li>Tea</li>
    <li>Milk</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```